# Execute a function after a redirection jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, redirect

I would like to execute a function after a redirection on my site. Here is my code:

```
$('a.filter-redirect').on('click', function(){

       window.location.replace('/technos/');
       filter();

});
```

And here is my function "filter":

```
$('a.filter-tech').on('click', function filter(){

        var tag = $(this).attr('rel');
        var val_input = $('#tag').val();

        if(tag === val_input){

            $('#tag').val('');
            $('#form').submit();

        }

        if(val_input){

            $('#tag').val(val_input + ',' + tag)

        }

        $('#tag').val(tag);
        $('#form').submit();
        return false;
});
```

I am not an expert in JS and jQuery and the code may be wrong. My function works, but not after the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

when you redirect to a new page the scripts on the previous page are no more executed. So you have to call this function as soon as the new page is loaded e.g. on `$(window).load()` or `$(document).ready()` not on an click in previous page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var tag = $(this).attr('rel');
        var val_input = $('#tag').val();

        if(tag === val_input){

            $('#tag').val('');
            $('#form').submit();

        }

        if(val_input){

            $('#tag').val(val_input + ',' + tag)

        }

        $('#tag').val(tag);
        $('#form').submit();
        return false;

})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I see where you want to come but my function is already execute when I click on a link. How can I make the difference between the same page redirected and when I go on ? I have a page named "technos" with filter links inside which sort my articles. In an article, I have a link which had to redirect on "technos" page and then sorts my articles you know? It's not easy to explain that and I do my best :)

Comment: You can do all of your calculations and criteria checks on the first page and then redirect to the target page by passing results of calculations in querystrings in URL. on the target page get querystrings and decide what you want to do. @Beno

Comment: I apologize but I don't really understand... :/

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect your page location changes, which means that a new page is loaded and the old is gone.
To do some action in the new page you have to add it in that page (for example in the body on load or in a script tag)

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the new page, keep all your required code inside `$(document).ready()` or `window.load()`

Somthing like this

```
function runOnPageLoad() {
        alert('Hey There');
    }
    window.onload = runOnPageLoad;
```

Or in jquery as

```
  $(document).ready ( function(){
    alert('Hey There');
});​
```

Hope it helps